# Sqlite database handler android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a data(name) that is coming from two seperate table coming one at a time in sqlite in android..and i have to get all the record on the basis of that data(name)..

I tried the following query but it didn't work.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + 
                        GlobalConstants.EM_DESCRIPTION+ " , " + 
                        GlobalConstants.EM_TOTAL_AMOUNT +
                     " FROM " +
                        GlobalConstants.INCOME_MANAGER_TABLE_NAME+"," +
                        GlobalConstants.EXPENSE_MANAGER_TABLE_NAME+
                     " WHERE " +
                        " nameof_customer "+" = "+" '"+get_Name+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

then what query should i use

Answer (score 2):

You should use getReadableDatabase() method instead of getWritableDatabase() and check your fields name in the select query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below one ?

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Your_Table_Name WHERE nameof_customer = '"+name.trim()+"'", null);
```

Hopew this would help you.